# css overlay issue with topbar and header

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a div element on top bar but all the elements of the top bar get down to the header, how can I fix that?
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUpMn.png)

Comment: Please show your html and css code @Mr 3ko

Comment: i'm using wordpress you can check this website karaokemaza.com ( plz.. check with devtool if you can fix this ) and plz.. scroll the website once, this error comes when someone scroll the website and then click on topbar element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use "!important" rule on #site-header.

Please use this CSS after this https://karaokemaza.com/wp-content/cache/wpfc-minified/lcjpsnov/dkco4.css.

Screenshot :- https://prjain19.imgur.com/all

```
#site-header{z-index:100 !important;}
```

Comment: Overlapping elements with a larger z-index cover those with a smaller one

Comment: it's still not working   karaokemaza.com ( plz.. check with devtool if you can fix this ) and plz.. scroll the website once, this error comes when someone scroll the website and then click on topbar element

Comment: Don't worry. I have done this. Please check my edited comment and attached screenshot https://prjain19.imgur.com/all. 
You have to add important rule on this css. "#site-header{z-index:100 !important;}"

OR

You can add this css"#site-header{z-index:100 !important;}" after all the css

Comment: Your welcome. If my answered was useful for you. Can you please vote by on click up arrow. Please choose as a best answer to make my good performance.
Thank you for this.

Answer (score 0):

### please try this

Add `Position:static` to **topbar**

```
#topbar{
  position: static;
}
```

Comment: Please check @Mr 3ko